# Initializing ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm initializing some attributes of my model with `after_initialize` callback, but this callback gets called when the record is loaded from database, overwriting the saved values. Here is the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags

  after_initialize :init_tags

  def init_tags
    write_attribute :tags, []
  end
end
```

Is there any way to do it without changing the callback to

```
  def init_tags
    if not read_attribute :tags
      write_attribute :tags, []
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags

  after_initialize :init_tags

  def init_tags
    self.tags ||= []
  end
end
```

Which is equivalent to your second solution, only a bit shorter. The `save` method isn't called, but it shouldn't be a problem as this will only be used on the first initialization of the model, the value will be filled afterwards.